# Any plugin to show calendar and clock together?

Tags: jquery, plugins, calendar, clock

I need plug-in to display calendar and clock in my application is there any good plug-in available??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this list of [18 Best Collection Of jQuery Calendar and Clock Picker Plugins](http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/18-best-collection-of-jquery-calendar-and-clock-picker-plugins/) could be of some help?

**EDIT**
This one seems kind of nice: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar